# Deleting call log of a be number

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, calllog

I am using the following code to delete a particular number from the call log, but it is not working on Android Marshmallow:

```
String queryString = "NUMBER=" + number;
try {
    context.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, queryString, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I delete the call log on Android Marshmallow?

Comment: Just marshmallow? Or have you tried other versions? Do you need permissions to modify the call history?

Answer (score 0):

On Marshmallow you will need to `request` the permissions from user to read and write from call log

See official doc link below on how to request permissions 
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html